# what's the equivalent of mysql's system variable in Oracle?

Tags: mysql, oracle

I have heard that Oracle uses "instance parameters".

Is this the equivalent of system variable of mysql?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oracle uses many different things. I suspect what you are asking about are properly called **initialization parameters**. Some of them may be equivalent to some MySQL server system variables. On the other hand, some of the MySQL system variables may be more like Oracle database session parameters.

I'm sure this answer is too general, but so is the question.